# ENUM Hibernate, не создаётся таблица

Tags: mysql, hibernate

Есть сущность, в которой одно из полей - enum.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCT")
public class Product {

@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

@Column(name = "NAME")
private String name;

@Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
private String description;

@Column(name="CONDITION")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Condition condition;
... getter-ы - setter-ы,
constructor-ы
```

enum

```
public enum Condition {
NEW  ,
USED}
```

С enum не создаётся сущность в базе (MySQL).

Comment: Непонятно с чем был связан глюк, но вопрос решился переименованием класса Enum (Conditions).

Answer (score 3):

Начиная со стандарта SQL-92, слово `CONDITION` является ключевым словом, т.е. имеет специфическое значение в синтаксисе языка. Поэтому таблица не может иметь имя `CONDITION`.

В подобных случаях применяется экранирование при помощи обратных апострофов (англ. backticks - ``). То есть ваша таблица должна называться `` `CONDITION` ``.  Чтобы добиться этого, явно задайте имя таблицы через аннотацию `@Table` или для Hibernate 3.5 и выше включите в конфигурации опцию `hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers`.